# how to get all field on modelform on django

Tags: django

I have a model called Product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id
    name
    nation
    Number
    price
```

i want to filter using all of the above attributes, which will be passed in query_params

at this moment i am using DjangoFilterBackends with filter_fields but to support all attributes i have to mention all the attributes in filter_fields like below in views

```
filter_fields = ['id', 'name', 'nation', 'Number', 'price']
```

its working fine, but in actual model the fields are alot, which is causing code quality degradation.

is there any way to include all fields in filter_fields ?? i tried `filter_fiels = ['__all__']`, but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your code like this:

```
filter_fields = '__all__'
```